# Functional way of joining two js object arrays based on common id

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I am trying to acheive something similar to SQL table join,
in the most elegant (functional) way, preferably with underscore.js,
so no for loops please.

I need to merge objects from two different arrays, matched upon a common identifier.

**For example, given:**

```
var basic = [{
              id: '1',
              name: 'someName',
             }, 
             {...} ]

var ext= [{
              id: '1',
              job: 'someJob',
             }, 
             {...} ]
```

**Result should be:**

```
var combined = [{
                 id: '1',
                 name: 'someName',
                 job: 'someJob',
                }, 
                {...} ]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `for` loops? Do you think recursion is the only way to work through a data structure in a functional way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map, findWhere and extend should do the trick:

```
var combined = _.map(basic, function(base){
    return _.extend(base, _.findWhere(ext, { id: base.id} ));
});
```

**Edit**:

If performance is an issue create a hash of the extended values:

```
var extHash = _.reduce(ext, function(memo, extended, key){
    memo[extended.id] = extended;
    return memo;
}, {});
```

and use like so:

```
var combined = _.map(basic, function(base){
    return _.extend(base, extHash[base.id]);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/FhjQ5/)</kbd>

Comment: I am worried about performance because of the use of findWhere

Comment: You didn't mention performance in the question, and these days js processing within modern browsers is highly optimised. If you do have issues then you could create a hash of the ext objects and use that in the map instead of findWhere.

Answer (score 0):

**NO LOOP :** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/h3hQt/2/

```
   basic=basic.sort(function(a,b){return a.id-b.id});
    ext=ext.sort(function(a,b){return a.id-b.id});
    var combined=basic.map(function(e,i){return inherits(e,ext[i]) });
```

---

Known that ,`inherits` are as following:

```
function inherits(base, extension)
{
   for ( var property in base )
   { 
         extension[property] = base[property];
   }
    return extension ;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `mapWithIndex` and a standard `.map()` (or `_.map`)?